# Undo changes to model attribute java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a method in a controller which gets a Flavour object from a jsp. This controller then returns a page (edit-flavour.jsp) where the user can change some things about this Flavour object and can choose to save or cancel the edits.

How can I make it so that when the user clicks on cancel, the flavour object I added into the model doesn't get affected from the changes?

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("iceCreamList")
@RequestMapping("/icecream*")
public class IceCreamController {

    @GetMapping("/new-flavour")
    public String showNewFlavourForm(Model model) {
        
        if (model.getAttribute("iceCreamList") == null) {
            model.addAttribute("iceCreamList", new IceCreamList());
        }

        return "/icecream/new-flavour";
    }
```

From new-flavour.jsp, when the user clicks on the *Add flavour* btn, we go to:

```
    @PostMapping("/addFlavour")
    public String addFlavour(Model model, 
                                        @ModelAttribute("iceCreamList") IceCreamList flavours,
                                        @Valid @ModelAttribute("flavour") Flavour flavour,
                                        BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/icecream/new-flavour";
        }
        //I save the new flavour so that the whole list of 
        //flavours can be displayed in show-flavours.jsp
        flavours.addFlavour(flavour);

        model.addAttribute("flavours", flavours);
        
        return "/icecream/show-flavours";
    }
```

show-flavours.jsp contains a table where each row shows a flavour and
has a button to modify the flavour.

When clicking on the *Modify* btn, we go to:

```
    @PostMapping("/modifyFlavour")
    public String modifyFlavour(Model model,
                                @ModelAttribute("iceCreamList") IceCreamList flavours,
                                @ModelAttribute Flavour flavour){

        flavours.remove(flavour);
        
        model.addAttribute(flavour);
        
        return "/icecream/edit-flavour";
    }
```

edit-flavour.jsp is essentially the
same as new-flavour.jsp but the fields
are already populated with the flavour I
want to edit.

After modifying the flavour the user can
choose to either save the changes or
cancel them. Here's the controller method that
handles that part:

```
    @PostMapping("/editFlavour")
    public String editReservationCustomer(Model model,
                                        @ModelAttribute("iceCreamList") IceCreamList flavours,
                                        @Valid @ModelAttribute("flavour") Flavour modFlavour,
                                        BindingResult result,
                                        @RequestParam("action") String action) {
            
        if(action.equals("save")) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "/icecream/edit-flavour";
            }
            //I add the new modified flavour to the list
            flavours.addFlavour(modFlavour);
            
            return "/icecream/show-flavours";
            
        }else if (action.equals("cancel")) {
            \\What to do here??
        }

    }

    
}
```

As you can see I edit an object in IceCreamList by removing it from the list, giving the possibility to the user to change it
and then adding it back again in the list.

But, If the user changes something and
then clicks on cancel, the changes
will have already affected the Flavour modFlavour
so I only have the modified flavour object and I lost all references to the original.

Comment: @JDK share the controller for `/icecream/edit-flavour` there the change must happen

Answer (score 0):

From the description, what I understood:

Once the user clicks on the flavor, you will render some new page stating the selected flavor and its details. User might be able to customize the flavor object again.

Answer:

Send the selected flavor object without saving from `/modifyFlavour` to the front-end, display details of flavor object, enable customizations like as a form. Once clicked on save, send the object back to another `POST` method `/saveFlavour` for saving it with all the required details. If cancelled you can close the section, no need to send a request to the backend.

Comment: I actually have to save the new Flavour object so that it can be displayed in show-flavours.jsp. I added the controller's code If you'd like to take a look.

Comment: Why to remove the selected flavor from the list. If the user modifies the flavor then just update the corresponding object in the list of flavors at the /editFlavor with the help of some identifier. If there was no modification no need to do any thing as we didn't remove the flavor and so it will remain available.